# Can someone give me a single example of the interrogative pronoun Welches? ( it is the genitiv of Welcher)

Tags: pronoun, interrogative

How do we use this interrogative pronoun in a sentence? It is the genitiv of Welcher.

I want an example of *Welcher* as a pronoun not as a determiner in a sentence.

Comment: Will you give me an example of Welches used as a pronoun, not as a determiner? Herr Vogt?

Comment: Person A: "Thomas Mann hat so tolle Bücher geschrieben." Person B: "Welches gefällt Dir am besten?" However, AFAIK the interrogative pronoun "welches" is not genitiv.

Comment: I am using Hammer's Grammar and it says that welcher is used as an interrogative pronoun and determiner and that it declines like dieser . So the genitiv form of Welcher would be welches just like here https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/welcher

Comment: @meh I believe in my example "welches"  is nominative neuter. If the first person talked about flowers, I'd use "welche"  (nominative feminine) and not "welcher" (genitive feminine).

Comment: If you need a genitive example: "Der Gesang welches Vogels gefällt Dir am besten?" (But I'm not sure it's technically a pronoun then.)

Comment: @Roland shouldn't that be _welchen Vogels_?

Comment: @phipsgabler Meines Wissens ist beides zulässig.

Answer (score 0):

The noun phrase that *welches* attaches to has to be in the genitive case. Examples can be produced easily and aplenty:

> Welches [Vorfalls] erinnerst du dich gerade?
> Welches [Verbrechens] werde ich beschuldigt?
> Welches [Menschen] wollen sie sich erbarmen?
> Auf den Sieg welches Vereins hat sie gewettet?
> Man rätselt, welches Kunden Bündel 200er seit Wochen nicht abgeholt wird.

(Expressions in brackets are optional. If omitted then *welches* is used as pronoun, and as determiner otherwise.)

Comment: It is true that examples of Welcher as a determiner can be produced aplenty ( just like you did) but what about examples of welches as a PRONOUN? In none of the sentences you have written is welcher used as a pronoun.

Comment: Your first and second example are wrong/at least very uncommon. If the substantive in genitive ends on "s" or "es" and is masculine or neuter, "welches" commonly mutates to "welchen". Either use a noun that is feminine, or one whose genitive doesn't end in "s"

Comment: @tofro: The examples are perfectly grammatical. How common these forms are is not as absolutely decided as you suggest. _welches_ is a masculine and neuter form. It cannot be used with a feminine noun.

Answer (score 0):

Welches is just the form of welcher/welche/welches that goes with the neutrum gender. It also sometimes goes with the maskulinum in genitiv.

> Welches Kleid ist am schönsten? (nominativ neutrum)
>
> Den Sommer welches Jahres hast du am besten in Erinnerung? (genitiv neutrum)
> ("Den Sommer welchen Jahres..." is also possible here though)
>
> Welches Kleid hast du dir ausgesucht? (akkusativ neutrum)
>
> Welches großen Fehlers war er sich schon damals bewußt? (genitiv masc.)
> ("Welchen Fehlers ..." is also possible if you leave out the attribute "großen")

Deklination Pronomen "welcher":

```
        Maskulin      Neutral     Feminin   Plural
Nom.    welcher       welches     welche    welche
Gen.    welches       welches     welcher   welcher
        (or welchen)  (or welchen)  
Dat.    welchem       welchem     welcher   welchen
Akk.    welchen       welches     welche    welche
```

Answer (score -3):

Its not a pronoun like *er,sie,es* etc... i

> Das Haus, welches von uns gebaut worden ist, wurde gestern abgerissen.
>
> The house which has been build by us, was destroyed yesterday.

> Ich habe den Fußball, welchen du mir geschenkt hast verloren.
>
> I lost the football which you gave me as a present.

and so on...

Comment: I am using Hammer's Grammar and it says that welcher is used as an interrogative pronoun and determiner and that it declines like dieser . So the genitiv form of Welcher would be welches